# Showing an image that have been received as a Blob object in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I'm working on a MEAN Stack app what i want to do is showing an image that's storage in the Data Base so the back-end worked but my real problem is in the front-end `Angular` so I did this

First receiving the image from the back end I made a service to do that

```
// Function to get user's profile image
  getProfileImage(){
      let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
                         .set('authorization', this.authToken);
    return this._http.get(this.domain + '/authentication/getProfileImage',{headers :httpHeaders,
      responseType: "blob"});

  }
```

That receive the image as Blob.

Second is in the `component.ts` i tried to convert the Blob to a file

```
imageToShow: any;

getImageFromService() {
      this.authService.getProfileImage().subscribe(data => {
        this.createImageFromBlob(data);
        console.log(data);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

this is the first method that get the image from the service and with using the `console.log(data);`

this what I get

```
Blob(763750) {size: 763750, type: "text/xml"}
```

and the size of it is the same file length in the Data Base so it worked to.

Now the second method that convert the Blob to an image

```
createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
     let reader = new FileReader();
     reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        this.imageToShow = reader.result;
        console.log(this.imageToShow);
     }, false);

     if (image) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(image);
     }
  }
```

and with `console.log(this.imageToShow);` what it's showing is this `data:text/xml;base64,/9j/4RE6RXhpZgAATU0A` a very long `string` that's a `base64` , so i add a `console.log(image);` in the `if` and what show me is this

```
Blob(763750) {size: 763750, type: "text/xml"}
```

so it didn't do a thing and in the HTML

```
<img [src]="imageToShow " alt="" class="img">
```

so what's wrong

Comment: text/xml? Image? What could go wrong...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First try to bind img tag to a variable that will be the url of your picture.
For example

```
<img [src]=imageUrl>
```

Then you need to use DomSanitizer

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer)
```

to bypassSecurityTrust of your unsafeUrl
and in your component when you retrieve the image you should create an url for the image like this

```
getImageFromService() {
    this.authService.getProfileImage().subscribe(data => {
        unsafeImageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(data);
        imageUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(unsafeImageUrl);
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

This will create a temporary url of your image which you can use in your binding

Comment: in witch method should i put the `imageUrl`

Comment: after this line `this.createImageFromBlob(data);`

Comment: `error TS2339: Property 'createObjectURL' does not exist on type '""'.` i get this

Comment: try with window.URL.createObjectURL(data)

Comment: i got an error `unsafe:data:image/png;base64,data:image/png;base64,undefined:1 GET unsafe:data:image/png;base64,data:image/png;base64,undefined 0 ()`

Answer (score 4):

This is how i do in Angular 9, downloading file from Rest and displaying.

```
image: SafeUrl | null = null;

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private api: ApiService) {}

download() {
    const mediaType = 'application/image';
    this.api.download(this.application.cover_photo_id).subscribe(value => {
      const blob = new Blob([value], { type: mediaType });
      const unsafeImg = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      this.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(unsafeImg);
    }, error1 => {

    });
}
```

Api service

```
download(fileId: string) {
    return this.http.get(Constants.downloadFile + `${fileId}`, {
      responseType: 'blob'
    });
}
```

Display

```
<img [src]="image" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Responsive image">
```