# Display image from API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I got problem how to display image send by API from backend it not display. And when I `console.log`, I got this error.

[image]

This is my code as your reference.

**HTML**

```
<img [src]="imageToShow" style="width:100%;margin-left: -14px;">
```

**Component**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getBanner()
}

    getBanner() {
        this.bannerId = {
          confId: 1,
          type: "Banner",
        };
        this.httpService.getBanner(this.bannerId).subscribe(
          (baseImage: any) => {
            let objectURL = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + baseImage.image;
            this.imageToShow = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
          },
          (error) => {
            // this.isImageLoading = false;
            console.log(error);
          }
        );
      }
```

**Service**

```
public getBanner(data){
    console.log(data)
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        responseType: 'blob',
        Authorization: 'Bearer '+this.getToken()
      })
    };
    return this.httpClient.post((this.serverUrl + this.basePath + '/landing/conferenceitem'),data,httpOptions);
  }
```

> **edit**

when I check up `Network Response` I got this image

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the API response is JSON?

Comment: I think the API is returing error . It is not at all going to success block .

Comment: The api is returning binary, you can convert it to base64

Comment: check my answer below.

Comment: When I checkup `Network response` I got image... Refer my question

Comment: @David I have add `baseImage.image` But it still not working

Comment: Have a look there https://stackoverflow.com/a/55592328 (1st method) and use `baseImage` instead of `baseImage.image`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

**Step #1**

Remove `Content-Type` header and set `responseType` to `blob` in `httpOptions`, but not in the header part like you did. Now, you should get a blob as a response. Before, angular was trying to parse your response as JSON, hence the error

```
public getBanner(data){
    console.log(data)
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        Authorization: 'Bearer '+this.getToken()
      }),
       responseType: 'blob'
    };
    return this.httpClient.post((this.serverUrl + this.basePath + '/landing/conferenceitem'),data,httpOptions);
  }
```

**Step #2** Use `baseImage` instead of `baseImage.image` (the response is a blob, it does not have an `image` property), and then use `createObjectURL` to get an image url from the blob. Sanitize that URL like your did

```
    this.httpService.getBanner(this.bannerId).subscribe(
      (baseImage: Blob) => {

       let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(baseImage);       
        this.imageToShow = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);

      },
      (error) => {
        // this.isImageLoading = false;
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I got this error on `(baseImage)` `Argument of type 'Blob' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`

Comment: full part `this.imageToShow = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(baseImage);`

Comment: Oops, corrected sorry : `this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL)`

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this is by Setting the response type to blob

```
const requestOptions: Object = {
/* other options here */
responseType: 'blob'
}

return this.httpClient.post((this.serverUrl + this.basePath + '/landing/conferenceitem'),data,requestOptions);
```

and you have to convert your image data to a dataURL:

```
   this.httpService.getBanner(this.bannerId).subscribe(
      (baseImage: any) => {
         this.imageToShow = baseImage;
      },
      (error) => {
        // this.isImageLoading = false;
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But when I add this `responseType: "blob"` i got this error `Cannot find name 'responseType'`

Comment: it should be set in the requestOptions/httpOptions in your case, check the edit

Comment: where should I add code for convert image data to dataURL

Comment: in your component.ts

Comment: In `getBanner(){}` ?

Comment: <img  src="data:image/png;base64,{{imageToShow }}"/>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50894572/showing-an-image-that-have-been-received-as-a-blob-object-in-angular-5

Answer (score 1):

**Change Your getBannerMethod as below :-**

```
getBanner() {
        this.bannerId = {
          confId: 1,
          type: "Banner",
        };
        this.httpService.getBanner(this.bannerId).subscribe(
          (baseImage: any) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            const url = reader.readAsDataURL(baseImage.image);
            reader.onloadend = () => this.imageToShow = reader.result;
          },
          (error) => {
            // this.isImageLoading = false;
            console.log(error);
          }
        );
      }
```

**Working Stackblitz** :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvicvq

Comment: error now, can you show me? or can provide a stackblitz?

Comment: updated code above with a working stackblitz example url

Comment: check my stackblitz, its works. some problem at your backend.

Comment: also i believe you should use baseImage not baseImage.image

Comment: when I add `{responseType: 'blob'}` like this `return this.httpClient.post((this.serverUrl + this.basePath + '/landing/conferenceitem'),data,httpOptions, {responseType: 'blob'});` I got this error `Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 4`

Comment: return this.httpClient.post((this.serverUrl + this.basePath + '/landing/conferenceitem'),data, {...httpOptions, responseType: 'blob'});

Comment: when I try to display image it come out like this `data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABHQAAAE5CAYAAADx8`

Comment: using my code, can you give a stackblitz?? or a git repo?